# My Site - User Profile service

Tags: my-site, administration, user-profile-service

I have few short questions about relations between "My Site" and UP/UPSync services.

1. Can I, normally, use User profile service without having My Site configured?
2. Can I, normally, use User profile sync service without having My Site configured?
3. If answer to above questions is "Yes", can I (in case that I have already configured "My Site" web app with some sync-ed data), just delete this "My Site" web app without bad influence on user profile data (will existing data will be preserved)?

Basically, I need to preserve that my UP and UPSync services continue work normally and that my UP data (part of properties are custom ones) remain untouched by My Site removal. Is that possible?

Comment: Just a question: Why do you want to delete the MySite app?

Comment: I provide user info via custom web parts, and there is no need anymore for MySite forms. Other reasons are: i can keep some additional space on file system/DB/memory,  I can restrict users to only my forms, I can save some of my time by avoiding to write user manual for that parts ;), ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thats fine. However, since you have already created the MySite host I suggest to restrict the "Create MySite" permission. So you can keep the web app, keep all features that might be tied to it AND you keep your users away from using/creating/playing around with their MySites. In addition, if you deside (some day) to use MySites, you don't have to struggle with the re-provision.

To disable MySite creation for your users see [here](http://toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=222):

Comment: Agreed, this is the way to go.  We don't use the MySites but we keep everything installed and provisioned but redirect to our own pages and Web Parts.

Comment: Also, rather than delete the web app, just restrict permissions to it in the My SIte Settings.

Comment: Thanx guys! I didn't get absolutely precise answers to my questions (which should be useful to someone someday) but this should be solution good enough for me.